# How to apply CSS to included HTML elements from php?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a main framework, where I include the menu for example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class="pic">
<?php 
include 'header.php';
?>
</div>

<div class="menu">
<?php 
include 'menu.php';
?>
</div>
...
</body>
</head>
```

But when I try to change individual buttons located within menu.php, the CSS is not applied.

menu.php:

```
<?php
echo '<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="home" class="menubtn" style="display: inline-block;">Home</button>
<button type="submit" name="login" class="menubtn" style="display: inline-block;">Login</button>
<button type="submit" name="register" class="menubtn" style="display: inline-block;">Register</button>
</form>';
```

?>

style.css:

```
.menubtn {
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:15px;
border-radius:12px;
background:#9C9C9C;
font-color:#FFFFFF;
border: 10px solid green;
```

}

How can I overcome this? pls help

edit: cleared cache, worked. thanks guys

Comment: Your code looks ok, show us your final html and css code (browser output) and describe, what is not working.

Comment: The CSS is not being applied on the individual buttons, I cant give link because is located on a localhost but [link](http://imgur.com/a/Nn7c1) its clear from here that it isnt working lol

Comment: well sick just tried it on chrome and its working. in which case my question is how can i make it support firefox?

Comment: I don't want a link. You have to update your question and provide all necessary info.
Your code is absolutely ok, it should work in Firefox. Maybe your page is only cached and you see old data.

Comment: Nobody asked you to get access to your page. You were asked to show the source code received in firefox. When it works in Chrome, it should work in FF as well. Clear the browser cache. Try [Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency = 1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency) on the URL `about:config` in your development profile.

Answer (score 2):

kindly clear the cache of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Cache Reloader - I use all the time, you can also bind a key to refresh. I works brilliantly.

**Chrome:**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-reloader/dnfpcpfijpdhabaoieccoclghgplmpbd?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog